# Repetitive patterns in data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series like shown in the image:

[image]

where in the x-axis is the Time variable and in the y-axis there is a numerical variable Y.
If I zoom inside the time range `[2020-02-01 14:09:00 , 2020-02-03 07:46:00]` I find these two equal peaks in the center, that probably are repeated within the whole time series.

[image]

Probably within the time series, along with these peaks there are others with other structures, etc.

How could I spot these peculiar behaviors in a time series?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `statsmodels.tsa` package has something for it